# need to insert some value after a particular tag in HTML

Tags: jquery, html

Hi Have one trick problem, I have table like this

```
<table id="tableID">
   <tbody>
    <span>
      <tr>
         <td>Row 1 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Row 2</td>
      </tr>
    </span>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to insert one more tr in above table before span closing tag through Jquery.

currently I am doing like this

```
$("#tableID tbody ").append(tr);
```

Any suggestion and help?

Thanks!

Comment: Invalid HTML you can't wrap tr with span. The span will close itself outside table

Comment: actually I am using jsf component <dataList> which generating <span> on runtime, and as per my requirement user can append row at run time.so I need to append it now before </span> tag

Comment: @user3194412 — It's still invalid and browsers will perform error recovery form it in different ways. You need to fix that and not use a span there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `span` here since it's invalid markup at this moment

After that, you can use [after](http://api.jquery.com/after/):

```
$('#tableID > tbody > tr:last-child').after('<tr class="newTr"><td>Row 3</td></tr>');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2LWFR/)**

Comment: Yes I got the answer, I try with this $("#tableID tbody span ").append(tr); and It is working.... :)

Comment: @user3194412 please post your ans ..not in comment..and mark it correct

Comment: @Pilot Posted Answer, but it is not allowing me to mark it correct.

Comment: @user3194412 you cannot mark your ans as correct before 12 hours..So wait and please go through stack meta sections

Answer (score 0):

Yes I tried with this

```
$("#tableID tbody span").append(tr);
```

And This is working fine!!

Regards.
Ashish